# How can i add Country Name or flag Display on Ordered page Panel Grid?

Tags: custom-options, magento-community, order-grid, grid-layout, country-regions

I need to show Country Name or flag on ordered  page, How can i add custom field on ordered panel grid?

Comment: Do you mean the shipping country name/flag in sales ordered grid?

Comment: Yes, how can i do that

Answer (score 1):

Refer this for  [Country Column in order grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24421355/magento-how-to-add-country-column-in-orders-grid-filter) and replace the below code,

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());


$collection->getSelect()->join('sales_flat_order_address', 'main_table.entity_id = sales_flat_order_address.parent_id',array('country_id' ) )->where("sales_flat_order_address.address_type =  'shipping'");

        $this->setCollection($collection);

        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }
```

Comment: could you pls join chat,,,

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48335/http-magento-stackexchange-com-questions-144418-how-can-i-add-country-name-or-f